# Unable to open DISPLAY with JavaFX on ubuntu server

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, xvfb

I have a simple Application which generates a png of a chart which is based on JavaFX. The app fails to run on displayless machine with the following exception, I don't need to render or display content on the console, just need to create the image.

```
"main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:68)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:257)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.initFx(JFXPanel.java:215)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.<init>(JFXPanel.java:230)
```

I'm trying to run this on a AWS instance. Is there a way to overcome this issue? Following is my sample code.

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String chartGenLocation = "/Users/tmp";
        new JFXPanel();
        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new PieChart.Data("Failed", 10),
                        new PieChart.Data("Skipped", 20));
        final PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
        chart.setAnimated(false);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            Scene scene = new Scene(chart, 500, 500);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            WritableImage img = new WritableImage(500, 500);
            scene.snapshot(img);

            File file = new File(Paths.get(chartGenLocation, "a.png").toString());
            try {
                ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(img, null), "png", file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //logger.error("Error occurred while writing the chart image
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have seen few SO answers which mostly talk about monocle and testfx, here I'm unable to add external dependencies. So adding testfx is not a option. I have also tried the following with xvbf, which hangs the system,

```
Xvfb :95 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &> xvfb.log &
export DISPLAY=:95.0
```

When I execute I see the following output and system hangs there.

```
(process:13112): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
```

**Update**

Execution Sequence

```
Xvfb :92 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &> xvfb.log &
export DISPLAY=:92.0
```

No errors in xvbf.log, seems to start properly.

```
java Test
```

I see following in console out

```
(process:13356): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
```

I do not see any log in xvbf.log, the execution doesn't proceed after the above log. My image is not getting generated.

**Update 2**

I would like to know if there is a way to bypass [this validation](https://github.com/loveyoupeng/rt/blob/master/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/glass/ui/gtk/GtkApplication.java#L67) since I really don't need a display rendering.

Comment: Do you get another prompt after the two warnings.... exactly what do you mean "system hangs"? And did you run the commands exactly as posted here?

Comment: Hi @ElliottFrisch thanks for the prompt reply, I have updated the question.

Comment: **And** you silently swallow any exceptions because? Does this code work anywhere?

Comment: It doesn't throw a IO exception, I have added a log and checked. Also this code works fine in my local machine.

Comment: Be sure that your `$LANG` and `$LANGUAGE` environment variables are set, and you have the necessary stuff to support said settings.  You may gain some insight from `man locale`

Comment: @ycr did you manage to resolve this issue? I have exactly the same demand (wanting to run JavaFX on Linux Ec2 instance) and hitting same headache!

Comment: @NickB I dug through my old code and added what worked for me as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same JavaFX issue on Ubuntu server using xvfb as the display manager for my UI tests, the root cause for me was my forwarded DISPLAY wasn't injected into dbus's activation environment, so anything that dbus activates that tries to present a UI failed to connect to a display and resulted in the "Unable to open DISPLAY" exception.

Running `dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DISPLAY XAUTHORITY` in that shell before launching the UI tests fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Starting a virtual display server resolved the issue for me.

```
# Starting a virtual display to support FX chart generation
echo "Starting Xvfb virtual display for chart generation"
export DISPLAY=:95
nohup Xvfb :95 -screen 0 1024x768x16 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Then before executing the Java executable set the DIAPLAY variable to the following.

```
export DISPLAY=:95.0
```

Comment: Thanks @ycr but that didn't resolve anything for us sadly. Did you just run this prior to launch the JavaFX jar? Were there any previous steps in terms of Xauthority or specific Xvfb installs or any setup you had to do inside your ec2 linux instance to get this going? I've never had to use any of this Xvfb/X11 and its doing my head in!

Comment: @NickB I can't exacty remember. But looking at the code, this is what I did. Starting the display server in the instance (https://github.com/yasassri/testgrid/blob/master/jenkins/slave-setup/ec2-slave-setup.sh#L59C1-L60C56) then before executing the executable setting the display variable to :95.0 https://github.com/yasassri/testgrid-jenkins-library/blob/dev/src/org/wso2/tg/jenkins/executors/TestGridExecutor.groovy#L169 Maybe the decimal point to specify the screen number makes a difference in the JVM, hence try that.